# set the tag of textFIeld

Tags: objective-c

I'm Having a custom cell which is consist of 3 different textfield txtsq,txtPOB,txtRxunit , and this custom  cell m taking in my table view Controller, in table view Controller class inside the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath , now i want to set the 3 different range limit of my    3 different text field which is in custom cell but i fail to set range in my

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string{
  NSString *resultStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

  if (textField.tag ==SQ) {

    if([self isNumeric:resultStr]){
      if(resultStr.length <= 3){
        if(resultStr.length >= 1){
          NSString *firstLetter = [resultStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
          if(![firstLetter isEqualToString:@"0"]){
            return YES;
          }
        }
        else{
          return YES;
        }
      }
    }
  }else

  if([self isNumeric:resultStr]){
    if(resultStr.length <= 5){
      if(resultStr.length >= 1){
        NSString *firstLetter = [resultStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        if(![firstLetter isEqualToString:@"0"]){
          return YES;
        }
      }
      else{
        return YES;
      }
    }
  }

  return NO;
}
```

I have already defined `cell.txtSQ.tag=SQ;`

```
cell.txtPOB.tag =POB;
cell.txtRxUnit.tag=RXunit;
```

After using this code my table view data is not persistent.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (self.skuNameArray.count > 0) {


        OrderCell *cell = nil;
        cell = (OrderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OrderCell"];

        if(cell == nil){

            cell = (OrderCell *)[OrderCell cellFromNibNamed:@"OrderCell"];
        }

        // Set Tag
        cell.tag            = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtSQ.tag      = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtPOB.tag     = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtRxUnit.tag  = indexPath.row;


//      cell.txtSQ.tag=SQ;


        //set Delegate
        cell.txtPOB.delegate = self;
        cell.txtRxUnit.delegate = self;
        cell.txtSQ.delegate = self;

        //set Values
        cell.lblSKU.text        =   self.skuNameArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.txtSQ.text         =   self.sqArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.txtPOB.text        =   self.pobArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.txtRxUnit.text     =   self.rxUnitArray[indexPath.row];


        if (self.index == PCP || self.index == CURRENT_DAY_REPORTING_DETAIL) {

            cell.txtSQ.enabled = NO;
            cell.txtRxUnit.enabled = NO;
            cell.txtPOB.enabled = NO;
        }
            [cell.txtSQ     addTarget:self action:@selector(sqChanged:)     forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];
            [cell.txtPOB    addTarget:self action:@selector(pobChanged:)    forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];
            [cell.txtRxUnit addTarget:self action:@selector(rxUnitChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];





        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

         return cell;

    }
```

Comment: The problem is not the tag, but the fact that your tableview reuses cells. You will have to make sure that the method cellforrowatindexpath fills your current cell with the right textview & tag. Maybe you should post that cellforrowatindexpath and the way you build your cell

Comment: The `shouldChange` method is the answer I told yesterday, I think if you write a method with resultString as param will be better.  Maybe you list the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code will help to solve it soon. Hope can help you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQ may be dynamic . So, make it static.

or

you might not have set delegate to self. Do this :

```
cell.txtSQ.delegate = self;
cell.txtPOB.delegate = self;
cell.txtRxUnit.delegate = self;
```

Set your tag carefully :

```
// Set Tag
cell.txtSQ.tag      = SQ;
cell.txtPOB.tag     = POB;
cell.txtRxUnit.tag  = RXunit;
```

Comment: HAve you set delegate...pls show your code for cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: yes alredy set delegate  cell.txtPOB.delegate = self;
                         cell.txtRxUnit.delegate = self;
                         cell.txtSQ.delegate = self;

Comment: is your control coming to these functions ?

Comment: whatever i have entered in my textfield this will come to my this function .

Comment: i added  cell for rowatindex please see to it

Comment: See carefully ..you haven't put tags carefully

Comment: m doing that which you answer but the this is that in my cellforRowAtIndex  cell.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtSQ.tag      = indexPath.row ;
        cell.txtPOB.tag     = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtRxUnit.tag  = indexPath.row;  writing this line also this line set persistent of my data ..

Comment: What you are saying ?

Comment: if you see in cellForRowAtIndexPath function i alredy set this tags but i also set cell.tag            = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtSQ.tag      = indexPath.row ;
        cell.txtPOB.tag     = indexPath.row;
        cell.txtRxUnit.tag  = indexPath.row; this tag so both the tags are clash and whtevr the value m enterng in ma text field they are not persistent ?

Comment: Dont set `cell.txtSQ.tag      = indexPath.row;
    cell.txtPOB.tag     = indexPath.row;
    cell.txtRxUnit.tag  = indexPath.row;` these tags

Comment: Set only what i have said in my answer

Comment: but when m not writing this line my table data is not persistent it will move from one text field to another y so ???